# Change column value when matching condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to replace a `NULL` value in a column only when other conditions are matched.

```
Columns: Parent, Child, flag01, lag02
```

Parent columns has many `NULL` values, but I want to replace the `null` values only when `flag01` and `flag02` is "ok".

If `flag01` and `flag02` are both "`Ok`" and Parent is NULL, replace to 'CT_00000'. Else, keep the original value (when NOT NULL).

Comment: and which RDBMS are we talking about ?!

Comment: Oracle. The point is that I don't want to update, just retrieve with a SELECT statement.

Comment: @LucasRezende : Have a look at my answer for retrieving record as per your condition. Hope it will help you to get your problem solved.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So as I though you want a select statement.

```
select case when (parent is null and flag01 = 'OK' and flag02 = 'OK') 
       then 'CT_00000'
       else parent end as columnSomeName,
       Child, flag01, lag02
 from yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thougth that but for some reason something have blocked my mind for something as trivial like this.

Answer (score 11):

```
UPDATE Table_Name
SET   Column_Name = 'CT_00000'
WHERE flag01 = 'OK'
AND   flag02 = 'OK'
AND   Parent IS NULL
```

just to select data

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (flag01 = 'OK' AND flag02 = 'OK' AND Parent IS NULL)
            THEN 'CT_00000'
            ELSE Column_Name END AS Column_Name
FROM Table_Name
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to update, just retrieve with a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at below SQL Query :

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN 
            LOWER(flag01) = 'ok' and 
            LOWER(flag02) = 'ok' 
        then 
            ISNULL(Parent, 'CT_00000')
        ELSE 
            Parent 
    END AS 'Parent', 
    flag01, 
    flag02 
FROM 
    [TableName]
```

Comment: This looks like SQL-Server, not Oracle (see comment on the OP)

Comment: and tag is SQL. Confused.

Comment: [tag:sql] refers to the language, as opposed to [tag:sqlserver]. You can run SQL queries on MS SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, MySQL or any other database...

Comment: SQL is SQL. ANSI. That's what I need.

Answer (score 3):

If you search for an update:

```
Update tablename
set Parent = 'CT_00000'
Where Parent is null
and flag01 = 'Ok'
and flag02 = 'Ok'
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to update, just retrieve with a SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1):

I am writing in SQL server, you can have equivalent for others too

```
Update myTable
set Column_name=ISNUll(Column_name,'CT_00000')
WHERE flag01 = 'OK'
AND   flag02 = 'OK'
AND   Parent IS NULL
```

or Alternatively

```
Update myTable
set Column_name='CT_00000'
WHERE flag01 = 'OK'
AND   flag02 = 'OK'
AND Column_name is null
AND   Parent IS NULL
```

For select Query

in SQL Server

```
Select ISNUll(Column_name,'CT_00000')
    from myTable
    WHERE flag01 = 'OK'
    AND   flag02 = 'OK'
    AND   Parent IS NULL
```

in Oracle

```
 Select NVL(Column_name,'CT_00000')
            from myTable
            WHERE flag01 = 'OK'
            AND   flag02 = 'OK'
            AND   Parent IS NULL
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to update, just retrieve with a SELECT statement.