# Showing a value in front end

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to show a different column value than what is in the DB column in a HTML page  using SQL. Here we do not want to update the column value in DB but only show a different value in HTML page using SQL.

For example:
Table1:

```
Row1: ID Name Role
1:    A1 Kumar PM
2:    A2 Prem  Developer
```

Now, I want to show in the HTML for the ID: A1, Name as 'Ramesh' instead of 'Kumar' using SQL. How to do this.

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: But how do you know to use Ramesh instead of Kumar?

Comment: What about the other rows? What do you want to show instead of "Prem"?

Comment: what is the logic to the modifications?

Comment: In any case a simple `case` will do.

Comment: DB: SQL Server,

Comment: It is a client requirement for particular ID row, Other rows need to be as is, no change required.

Comment: SQL doesn't display values in HTML. What language are you using?

Comment: Anything you do here will pretty much have to be hard coded which just screams of something gone wrong. I realize the client is the one asking but I would consider another column in the table for alias or something like that so that your solution is data driven.

Comment: One of several duplicates:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21551920/change-column-value-when-matching-condition

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL* you can use `case` expression for that :

```
select id, (case when id = 'A1' and name = 'Kumar'  
                 then 'Ramesh' else name 
            end) as Name, 
       Role
from table t;
```

Comment: Yeah, I would have done the same thing, but can't yet understand the question myself.